# Java loop- keeps on asking for user input

Tags: java

I looked at some other similar posts but was not able to figure out the solution, hence looking for your valuable input, thanks in advance.

**What I want**: You will be asked to enter a sign (`+` , `-`, `/`) and the output will display *"You entered minus"* (if your input was `-`)

**Class that takes the input**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TakeSign {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); /*Create an object of scanner class*/

    public char mySign() { 
        System.out.print("Enter a sign: ");
        char input2 = userInput.next().charAt(0);
        return input2;
    }
}
```

**Main Class**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        TakeSign ts = new TakeSign();
        if (ts.mySign() == '+') {
            System.out.println("You entered plus");
        }
        else if (ts.mySign() == '-') {
            System.out.println("You entered minus");
        }
        else if (ts.mySign() == '/') {
            System.out.println("You entered division");
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem**

If my 1st input is `/` (division) I get asked 3 times. I was expecting to be asked just 1 time.

```
Enter a sign: /
Enter a sign: /
Enter a sign: /
You entered division
```

I think the problem is in the loop which I probably did not write correctly. Can you please point me to right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use

```
 switch( ts.mySign() ){
 case '+':
     System.out.println ("You entered plus");
     break;
 case '-':
     System.out.println ("You entered mimus");
     break;
 case '*':
     System.out.println ("You entered asterisk");
     break;
 case '/':
     System.out.println ("You entered slash");
     break;
 default:
     System.out.println ("Input error");
     break;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to assign `ts.mySign()` to a variable and use that variable in your if statements

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TakeSign ts = new TakeSign();
    char sign = ts.mySign();
    if (sign == '+') {
        System.out.println("You entered plus");
    } else if (sign == '-') {
        System.out.println("You entered minus");
    } else if (sign == '/') {
        System.out.println("You entered division");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `mySign` method asks the user for input.  So if you call `ts.mySign()` three times, it will ask the user three times.  But this is what you're doing in your chain of `if` and `else` statements.

You need to call `ts.mySign()` *just once* before the `if` statements, assign the result to a variable, then just check the value of that variable in each of the `if` statements.

Comment: Thank You that explains the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling ts.mySign() 3 times in your if-statement.

Call it **once** and store it in a `variable` and then compare against your signs.

i.e.

```
char sign = ts.mySign();
if (sign == '+')
...
```